# Python Mixed Integer Nonlinear Optimization using GEKKO package

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, gekko

I'm trying develop a structural weight optimization of a Glass Reinforcement Plastic (GRP) High Speed Craft using MINLP and the GEKKO package. I need to consider many design variables as integers and other as real and continuous variables. To evaluate the constraints, I'm following the requirements of ISO 12215 part 5. This rule establishes the minimum structural requirements for a craft. The problem is that I need use many conditional like (*if, max or min*), I read that GEKKO changes these types of conditional statements because the traditional conditions are not continuous. Therefore, I use `m.if3`, `m.max3`, or `m.min3`. However, when I run the program these GEKKO conditional statements do not work. Many operations (intermediates) take infinity value because the program divides by zero and never converges to a solution. Any suggestions to understand the solver and obtain a successful solution?

My problem is relative short because has 20 design variables with around 15 constraints without time dependence.

```py
# Optimization (Longitudinal Framing).ipynb
from math import*
import glob,os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rcParams
from matplotlib.font_manager import FontProperties
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import time
from gekko import GEKKO

def span_space_stiff(nt,nl,lp,b):
    #---------------9. DIMENSIONS OF PANELS AND STIFFENERS------------------------
    # Bottom panel
    sl  = m.Intermediate(1000*b/(nl+1),name='sl')
    st  = m.Intermediate(1000*lp/(nt+1),name='st')

    #if nl < nt transversal arrangements is select by program 
    #if nt <= nl longitudinal arrangements is select by program 
    lul = m.Intermediate(st,name='lul')
    lut = m.Intermediate(1000*b,name='lut')

    return (st, sl, lut, lul)

def stiff_force(lwl,bc,v,beta,mldc,lut,st,lul,sl):
    # ---------7. PRESSURE ADJUST FACTORS ACCORDING TO ISO 12215 Part 5-----------
    # 7.2.- Design Category Factor (kDC) (Fixed value for Design Category B)
    kDC = m.Const(0.8,name='kdcr')

    # 7.3.- Dynamic Load Factor (nCG) in "g" units 
    nCG = (0.32*((lwl/(10*bc))+0.084)*(50-beta)*(((v*bc)**2)/mldc))
    if nCG >= 3:
        nCG = 0.5*v/(mldc**0.17)
    if nCG > 7:
        nCG = 7
    nCG = m.Const(nCG,name='ncgr')

    # 7.5.- Area pressure reduction factor (kAR)
    # Design area (AD)
    ad_t1 = m.Intermediate(0.33*(lut**2)*1e-6,name='ad_t1')
    ad_t2 = m.Intermediate((lut*st)*1e-6,name='ad_t2')
    AD_T = m.Intermediate(m.max3(ad_t1,ad_t2),name = 'ad_t')
    
    ad_l1 = m.Intermediate(0.33*(lul**2)*1e-6,name='ad_l1')
    ad_l2 = m.Intermediate((lul*sl)*1e-6,name='ad_l2')
    AD_L = m.Intermediate(m.max3(ad_l1,ad_l2),name = 'ad_l')
    
    kar_t1 = m.Intermediate((0.1*(mldc**0.15)/(AD_T**0.3)),name='kar_t1')
    kar_l1 = m.Intermediate((0.1*(mldc**0.15)/(AD_L**0.3)),name='kar_l1')
        
    # try using m.if3
    kar_t2 = m.Intermediate(m.if3(0.25-kar_t1,kar_t1,0.25),name='kar_t2')
    kar_l2 = m.Intermediate(m.if3(0.25-kar_l1,kar_l1,0.25),name='kar_l2')
    kAR_T  = m.Intermediate(m.if3(1-kar_t1,1,kar_t2),name='kar_t')
    kAR_L  = m.Intermediate(m.if3(1-kar_l1,1,kar_l2),name='kar_l')
    
    #-----------------8. DESIGN PRESSURE ISO 12215 part 5-------------------------
    #8.1.3.- Motor craft bottom pressure in planing mode in [kN/m2]
    pb_t = m.Intermediate(((0.1*mldc*(1+(kDC**0.5)*nCG))/(lwl*bc))*kAR_T
                        ,name='pb_t')
    pb_l = m.Intermediate(((0.1*mldc*(1+(kDC**0.5)*nCG))/(lwl*bc))*kAR_L
                        ,name='pb_l')

    #------------11.5 STIMATE DESIGN FORCE AND DESIGN BENDING MOMENT--------------
    fd_t = m.Intermediate(5*pb_t*st*lut*1E-4,name='fd_t')           #[N]
    fd_l = m.Intermediate(5*pb_l*sl*lul*1E-4,name='fd_l')           #[N]
    md_t = m.Intermediate(83.33*pb_t*st*(lut**2)*1E-9,name='md_t')  #[N m]
    md_l = m.Intermediate(83.33*pb_l*sl*(lul**2)*1E-9,name='md_l')  #[N m]

    return pb_t,pb_l,fd_t,fd_l,md_t,md_l

def plate_force(lwl,bc,v,beta,mldc,lut,st,lul,sl,bl,bt):
    #---------------------9.DIMENSION OF PANELS AND STIFFENERS--------------------
    #9.1.- Dimensions of bottom plating panels
    # Large dimension of planel [mm]
    l1 = m.max3(sl-bl,st-bt)
    # Short dimension of planel [mm]
    b1 = m.min3(sl-bl,st-bt)

    # ---------7. PRESSURE ADJUST FACTORS ACCORDING TO ISO 12215 Part 5-----------
    #7.2.- Design Category Factor (kDC) (Fixed value for Design Category B)
    kDC = m.Const(0.8,name='kdcp')  

    # 7.3.- Dynamic Load Factor (nCG) in "g" units 
    nCG = 0.32*((lwl/(10*bc))+0.084)*(50-beta)*(((v*bc)**2)/mldc)
    if nCG >= 3:
        nCG = 0.5*v/(mldc**0.17)
    if nCG > 7:
        nCG = 7
    nCG = m.Const(nCG,name='ncgp')

    # 7.5.- Area pressure reduction factor (kAR)
    # Design area (AD)
    ad1 = m.Intermediate((l1*b1)*1E-6,name='ad1')
    ad2 = m.Intermediate(2.5*(b1**2)*1E-6,name='ad2')    
    AD  = m.Intermediate(m.min3(ad1,ad2),name='ad')

    # try using m.if3
    kar1 = m.Intermediate(0.1*(mldc**0.15)/(AD**0.3),name='kar1')
    kar2 = m.Intermediate(m.if3(0.25-kar1,kar1,0.25),name='kar2')
    kAR  = m.Intermediate(m.if3(1-kar1,1,kar2),name='kar')

    #-----------------8. DESIGN PRESSURE ISO 12215 part 5-------------------------
    #8.1.3.- Motor craft bottom pressure in planing mode in [kN/m2]
    pbp = m.Intermediate(((0.1*mldc*(1+(kDC**0.5)*nCG))/(lwl*bc))*kAR
                         ,name='pbp') 

    #---------10.1.5 STIMATE FORCE AND BENDING MOMENT ON A PANEL------------------
    # Shear Strength aspect ratio factor (kSHC) (Table 12 - ISO 12215 part 5)
    kshc1 = m.Intermediate(0.035+0.394*(l1/b1)-0.09*((l1/b1)**2),name='kshc1')
    kSHC = m.Intermediate(m.if3(2-(l1/b1),0.5,kshc1),name='kshc')

    # Panel Aspec Ratio factor (k2) (Table 5 - ISO 12215 part 5)
    a1 = m.Intermediate(0.271*((l1/b1)**2)+0.910*(l1/b1)-0.554,name='a1')
    a2 = m.Intermediate(((l1/b1)**2)-0.313*(l1/b1)+1.351,name='a2')        
    k2 = m.Intermediate(m.if3(2-(l1/b1),0.5,a1/a2),name='k2')

    # shear force in middle of "b1"  [N/mm]
    fdp = m.Intermediate(1*kSHC*pbp*b1*(1E-3),name = 'fdp')
    # Bending moment in "b1" direction   [N mm/mm]
    mdp = m.Intermediate(83.33*2*k2*pbp*(b1**2)*(1E-6),name = 'mdp')

    return pbp, fdp, mdp, l1, b1

def bottom_optimize(lp,b,nt,nl,hL,bL,hT,bT,l1,b1,
                    st,lut,sl,lul,pbt,pbl,fdt,fdl,mdt,mdl,mdp):
    #----------STIMATE THE WEIGHT PER AREA, THICKNESS ADN YOUNG'S MODULUS---------
    # Bottom Plate 
    Amat = m.Intermediate(n1*Tmat[0]+n2*Tmat[1]
                      +n3*Tmat[2]+n4*Tmat[3],name='amat')
    Awr = m.Intermediate(n5*Twr[0]+n6*Twr[1],name='awr')
    Cmat = m.Intermediate(n1*Wmat[0]+n2*Wmat[1]
                      +n3*Wmat[2]+n4*Wmat[3],name='cmat')
    Cwr = m.Intermediate(n5*Wwr[0]+n6*Wwr[1],name='cwr')
    # Young's Modulus of bottom plate laminate [N/mm2]
    Ep   = m.Intermediate((6400**(4+2*(n1+n2+n3+n4))*(13240**(2*(n5+n6))))    
                      **(1/(4+2*(n1+n2+n3+n4+n5+n6))),name='ep')
    # Total laminated thickness [mm]
    B_T  = m.Intermediate((4*min(Tmat)+2*(Amat+Awr)),name='b_t')              

    #--------------LONGITUDINAL BOTTOM STIFFENER OPTIMIZATION---------------------
    # REQUIERED SHEAR AREA AND SECTIONAL MODULUS
    # [cm3] Req. SM in flange of longitudinal stifferners
    SM_Req_Long    = m.Intermediate((mdl)/(SigUT),name='smrl') 
    # [cm2] Req. webs shear area of longitudinal stifferners
    Awebs_Req_Long = m.Intermediate((fdl)/(100*Tao_MAT),name='awrl') 
    # [cm2] Req. cores shear area of longitudinal stifferners
    Acore_Req_Long = m.Intermediate((fdl)/(100*Tao_Core),name='acrl') 

    # WEIGHT AND THICKNESS OF BOTTOM LONGITUDINAL
    #BT_LS : thickness of bottom longitudinal stiffeners.
    BT_LS = m.Intermediate(N_bl1*Tmat[0]+N_bl2*Tmat[1]
                        +N_bl3*Tmat[2]+N_bl4*Tmat[3],name='bt_ls')
    #L_W   : weight of bottom longitudinal stiffeners.
    L_W   = m.Intermediate(N_bl1*Wmat[0]+N_bl2*Wmat[1]
                        +N_bl3*Wmat[2]+N_bl4*Wmat[3],name='l_w')

    # LONGITUDINALS STIFFENERS COMPUTATION
    a  = m.Intermediate(10+(N_bl1+N_bl2+N_bl3+N_bl4)*15,name='a')
    wp = m.Intermediate(20*B_T+bL,name='wp')
    EA = m.Intermediate(((Ep*wp*B_T)+(Ec*bL*hL)+
                        (Er*(a*BT_LS+2*hL*BT_LS+(bL+2*BT_LS)*BT_LS))),
                      name='EAL')
    EAZ = m.Intermediate(((Ep*wp*B_T*(0.5*B_T))+(Ec*bL*hL*(0.5*hL+B_T))+
                        (Er*((a*BT_LS*(B_T+0.5*BT_LS))+2*hL*BT_LS*(B_T+0.5*hL)
                        +BT_LS*(bL+2*BT_LS)*(B_T+hL+0.5*BT_LS)))),name='EAZL')
    NA   = m.Intermediate(EAZ/EA,name='NAL')
    Zcri = m.Intermediate(B_T+hL+0.5*BT_LS-NA,name='Zcri')
    EAZ2 = m.Intermediate(((Ep*wp*B_T*0.25*(B_T)**2)
                        +(Ec*((bL*(NA-B_T)*0.25*(NA+B_T)**2)+bL*(hL-NA+B_T)
                              *(0.25*(NA+hL+B_T)**2)))
                        +(Er*((2*BT_LS*(NA-B_T)*0.25*(NA+B_T)**2)
                              +(2*BT_LS*(hL-NA+B_T)*0.25*(NA+hL+B_T)**2)))
                        +(Er*((a*BT_LS*(B_T+0.5*BT_LS)**2)
                              +(bL+2*BT_LS)*BT_LS*((B_T+hL+0.5*BT_LS)**2))))
                      ,name='EAZ2L')
    Ebh3 = m.Intermediate((1/12)*((Ep*wp*(B_T**3))
                              +(Ec*bL*(((hL-NA+B_T)**3)+((NA-B_T)**3)))
                              +(Er*(a*(BT_LS**3)+(bL+2*BT_LS)*(BT_LS**3))))
                              ,name='Ebh3L')
    EIna = m.Intermediate(EAZ2+Ebh3-(NA**2)*EA,name='EInaL')
    Qc = m.Intermediate(((Ec*0.5*bL*(hL+B_T-NA)**2)
                      +(Er*(Zcri*BT_LS*(bL+2*BT_LS)+BT_LS*(hL+B_T-NA)**2)))
                      ,name='QcL')
    Qw = m.Intermediate(((Ep*(NA-0.5*B_T)*wp*B_T)
                      +(Er*((NA-B_T-0.5*BT_LS)*a*BT_LS))),name='QwL')
    EIminL =m.Intermediate((26*(1**1.5)*pbl*sl*(lul**3)*((1E-7)/0.05)),
                         name='EIminL')

    #DEFINE LONGITUDINAL CONSTRAINTS
    #Define longitudinal stiffeners constraints 
    # [cm3] actual section modulus for longitudinal stiffeners
    SML = m.Intermediate((0.001*EIna/(Er*Zcri)),name='sml')
    C1L = m.Intermediate((SML/SM_Req_Long),name='c1l')
    # [cm2] actual web shear area for longitudinal stiffeners
    AWL = m.Intermediate((0.01*EIna*2*BT_LS/Qw),name='awl')
    C2L = m.Intermediate((AWL/Awebs_Req_Long),name='c2l')
    # [cm2] actual core shear area for longitudinal stiffeners
    ACL = m.Intermediate((0.01*EIna*bL/Qc),name='acl')
    C3L = m.Intermediate((ACL/Acore_Req_Long),name='c3l')
    # [cm2] actual core shear area for longitudinal stiffeners
    EIL = m.Intermediate((EIna/EIminL),name='eil')
    # realtion for controle the local buckling in webs
    C45 = m.Intermediate((hL/BT_LS),name='c45')
    # realtion for controle the local buckling in flange 
    C46 = m.Intermediate((bL/BT_LS),name='c46')

    #---------------TRANSVERSAL BOTTOM STIFFENER OPTIMIZATION---------------------
    # REQUIERED SHEAR AREA AND SECTIONAL MODULUS
    # [cm3] Reg. SM in flange of transversal stiffeners
    SM_Req_Trans   = m.Intermediate((mdt)/(SigUT),name='smrt')
    # [cm2] Req. webs shear area of transversal stiffeners
    Awebs_Req_Trans= m.Intermediate((fdt)/(100*Tao_MAT),name='awrt')  
    # [cm2] Req. cores shear area of transversal stiffeners
    Acore_Req_Trans= m.Intermediate((fdt)/(100*Tao_Core),name='acrt')

    # WEIGHT AND THICKNESS OF BOTTOM TRANSVERSAL
    #BT_TS : thickness of bottom transversal stiffeners.
    BT_TS = m.Intermediate(N_bt1*Tmat[0]+N_bt2*Tmat[1]
                        +N_bt3*Tmat[2]+N_bt4*Tmat[3],name='bt_ts')
    #T_W   : weight of bottom transversal stiffeners.
    T_W   = m.Intermediate(N_bt1*Wmat[0]+N_bt2*Wmat[1]
                        +N_bt3*Wmat[2]+N_bt4*Wmat[3],name='t_w') 

    # TRANSVERSAL STIFFENERS COMPUTATION
    aT  =m.Intermediate((10+(N_bt1+N_bt2+N_bt3+N_bt4)*15),name='aT')
    wpT =m.Intermediate(20*B_T+bT,name='wpT')
    EAT =m.Intermediate((Ep*(wpT*B_T)+(Ec*bT*hT)+
                        (Er*(aT*BT_TS+2*hT*BT_TS+(bT+2*BT_TS)*BT_TS))),
                      name='EAT')
    EAZT =m.Intermediate(((Ep*wpT*B_T*(0.5*B_T))+(Ec*bT*hT*(0.5*hT+B_T))+
                        (Er*((aT*BT_TS*(B_T+0.5*BT_TS))+
                              2*hT*BT_TS*(B_T+0.5*hT)+
                              BT_TS*(bT+2*BT_TS)*(B_T+hT+0.5*BT_TS)))),
                        name='EAZT')
    NAT = m.Intermediate(EAZT/EAT,name='NAT')
    ZcriT =m.Intermediate(B_T+hT+0.5*BT_TS-NAT,name='ZcriT')   
    EAZ2T =m.Intermediate(((Ep*wpT*B_T*0.25*(B_T**2))+
                          (Ec*(bT*(NAT-B_T)*0.25*((NAT+B_T)**2)+
                              (bT*(hT-NAT+B_T)*(0.25*(NAT+hT+B_T)**2))))+
                          (Er*((2*BT_TS*(NAT-B_T)*0.25*(NAT+B_T)**2)+
                              (2*BT_TS*(hT-NAT+B_T)*0.25*(NAT+hT+B_T)**2)))+
                          (Er*((aT*BT_TS*(B_T+0.5*BT_TS)**2)+
                              (bT+2*BT_TS)*BT_TS*((B_T+hT+0.5*BT_TS)**2)))),
                        name='EAZ2T')
    Ebh3T =m.Intermediate((1/12)*((Ep*wpT*(B_T**3))+
                                (Ec*bT*(((hT-NAT+B_T)**3)+((NAT-B_T)**3)))+
                                (Er*2*BT_TS*(((hT-NAT+B_T)**3)+
                                              ((NAT-B_T)**3)))+
                                (Er*(aT*(BT_TS**3)+(bT+2*BT_TS)*(BT_TS**3)))),
                        name='Ebh3T')
    EInaT =m.Intermediate(EAZ2T+Ebh3T-(NAT**2)*EAT,name='EInaT')
    Qc_T =m.Intermediate(((Ec*0.5*bT*(hT+B_T-NAT)**2)
                      +(Er*(ZcriT*BT_TS*(bT+2*BT_TS)+
                            BT_TS*(hT+B_T-NAT)**2))),name='QcT')
    Qw_T =m.Intermediate(((Ep*(NAT-0.5*B_T)*wpT*B_T)+
                        (Er*((NAT-B_T-0.5*BT_TS)*aT*BT_TS))),name='QwT')
    EIminT =m.Intermediate((26*(1**1.5)*pbt*st*(lut**3)*((1E-7)/0.05)),
                         name='EIminT')

    # DEFINE TRANSVERSAL CONSTRAINTS
    # [cm3] actual section modulus for transversal stiffeners
    SMT = m.Intermediate(0.001*EInaT/(Er*ZcriT),name='smt')
    C1T = m.Intermediate((SMT/SM_Req_Trans),name='c1t')
    # [cm2] actual web shear area for transversal stiffeners
    AWT = m.Intermediate((0.01*EInaT*2*BT_TS/Qw_T),name='awt')
    C2T = m.Intermediate((AWT/Awebs_Req_Trans),name='c2t')
    # [cm2] actual core shear area for transversal stiffeners
    ACT = m.Intermediate((0.01*EInaT*bT/Qc_T),name='act')
    C3T = m.Intermediate((ACT/Acore_Req_Trans),name='c3t')
    # relation of stiffeness for transversal stiffeners
    EIT = m.Intermediate((EInaT/EIminT),name='eit')
    # relation for controle the local buckling in webs
    C47 = m.Intermediate((hT/BT_TS),name='c47')
    # relation for controle the local buckling in flange
    C48 = m.Intermediate((bT/BT_TS),name='c48')

    #----------------------TOTAL STIFFENERS WEIGHT--------------------------------
    L_Weight = m.Intermediate(((L_W*nl*lul/300)*((2*hL+bL+a)/1000)+
                          (hL*bL*lul*nl*dcore/(1000**3))),name='LS_weight')

    T_Weight = m.Intermediate(((T_W*nt*lut/0.3)*((2*hT+bT+aT)/1000)
                            +(hT*bT*nt*lut*dcore/1000**2))
                            ,name='TS_weight')

    #weight per length of mat in longitudinal stiffeners.
    lwl = m.Intermediate((L_W/0.3)*((2*hL+bL+a)/1000),name='lwlayer')
    #weight per length of core in longitudinal stiffeners.
    lwc = m.Intermediate(hL*bL*dcore/1000**2,name='lwcore')
    #weight per length of mat in transversal stiffeners
    twl = m.Intermediate((T_W/0.3)*((2*hT+bT+aT)/1000),name='twlayer')
    #weight per length of core in transversal stiffeners
    twc = m.Intermediate(hT*bT*dcore/1000**2,name='twcore')

    #---------------------------PLATE OPTIMIZATIONS-------------------------------
    # PLATE COMPUTATION
    # Sectional Inercia
    I    = m.Intermediate((((4*min(Tmat)+2*(Amat+Awr))**3)/12),name='I')
    # Distance to critical fiber
    Zcri = m.Intermediate((Amat+Awr)+1.5*min(Tmat),name='Zcrip')
    # Acting tension stress 
    Sact = m.Intermediate((mdp/(Ep*I/(Zcri*6400))),name='Sact')
    # Total Panel dimension in squared meters
    Panel_Dim  = lp*b
    # Local panel dimension in squared meters
    LPanel_Dim = m.Intermediate(l1*b1/(1000**2),name='Lpanel')

    # CONSTRAINTS
    #Sub-Laminate
    C1P = m.Intermediate(n1+n2+n3+n4-n5-n6,name='c1p')
    # Min. Weight per area [kg/m2]
    minWeight = m.Const((0.0675+0.0135*v*0.0675*(mldc**0.33)),name='minW')
    bweight = m.Intermediate((4*min(Wmat)/0.3)+
                            2*((Cmat/0.3)+(Cwr/0.48)),name='bweight')
    C2P = m.Intermediate((minWeight/bweight),name='c2p')
    #Norma stress acting on critical fiber
    C3P = m.Intermediate((SigUT/Sact),name='c3p')

    #---------OBJECTIVE FUNCTION FOR BOTTOM PANEL (panel weight in Kg )-----------
    PANEL_WEIGHT = m.Intermediate(Panel_Dim*bweight,name='pw')
    STIFF_WEIGHT = m.Intermediate((L_Weight+T_Weight),name='sw')
    BOTTOM_WEIGHTS = PANEL_WEIGHT+STIFF_WEIGHT 

    return (BOTTOM_WEIGHTS,PANEL_WEIGHT,STIFF_WEIGHT,
          C1L,C2L,C3L,EIL,C45,C46,C1T,C2T,C3T,EIT,C47,C48,C1P,C2P,C3P,
          B_T,Ep,twl,twc,lwl,lwc)

#=========================DEFINE SHIP PARAMETERS================================
LH   = 12.0     # [m]   Hull length
Lwl  = 10.74    # [m]   Legnth on design water line
BC   = 2.93     # [m]   Chine beam in meters
beta = 13       # [°]   Deadrise angle 
V    = 25       # [kn]  Maximun velocity 
mLDC = 8864     # [kg]  Design Displacement
T    = 0.51     # [m]   Draft
D    = 1.5      # [m]   Depth
#=============================FUNCTION PARAMETERS===============================
#DEFINE FUNCTION PARAMETERS 
Lp = 4    # 4x1.5 [m] global bottom panel dimension in "x" direction (Aft/Fwr)
B  = 1.5  # 4x1.5 [m] global bottom panel dimension in "y" direction (Br/Stbr)
Bs = 1.2  # 4x1.2 [m] global side panel dimension in "y" direction 
# it is necessary change the name of variable for functions COMPUTATION
lh,lwl,bc,v,mldc,lp,b,bside,d,t = LH,Lwl,BC,V,mLDC,Lp,B,Bs,D,T

#Permisibles stress, (Reverse Safe Factor = 0.4) (ISO 12215 part 5 Annex C)
SigUT     = 0.4*85     # N/mm2   ultimate tension stress MAT
Taoi_MAT  = 0.4*17.25  # N/mm2   ultimate intralaminar stress MAT
Taoi_WR   = 0.4*14.1   # N/mm2   ultimate intralaminar stress WR
Tao_MAT   = 0.4*62     # N/mm2   ultimate shear strength stress MAT
Tao_Core  = 0.4*16.7   # N/mm2   ultimate shear strength stress CORE
# Young's Modulus
Ec    = 17240       # N/mm2    young's modulus for Core material (CHANUL)
Er    = 6400        # N/mm2    young's modulus for MAT fibers

#Material properties (ISO 12215 part 5 Annex C)
dres  = 1.2                # g/cm3  Polyester resine density
dmat  = 2.56               # g/cm3  Mat ply density
dwr   = 2.56               # g/cm3  Waven Roven ply density
Wmat  =[0.3,0.35,0.45,0.6] # weigth per area (kg/m2) 
                           #  of Mat plies (300,350,450,600) grams.
Wwr   =[0.6,0.8]           # weigth per area (kg/m2) of WR plies (600,800) grams
dkeel = 870                # Kg/m3    Keel Core density (chanul) 
dcore = 870                # Kg/m3    Stiffeners Core density (chanul) 

#Thickness of each layer 
Tmat = np.zeros(len(Wmat))
Twr  = np.zeros(len(Wwr))
for i in range(len(Wmat)):
    Tmat[i] = (Wmat[i]/(dres*dmat))*((dmat/0.3)-(dmat-dres))
for i in range(len(Wwr)):
    Twr[i] = (Wwr[i]/(dres*dwr))*((dwr/0.48)-(dwr-dres))

#======================OPTIMIZATION OF BOTTOM PANELS============================
#Initial point for bottom optimization
n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6 = 10,10,2,2,10,1
NL, NT =1,1
N_bl1, N_bl2, N_bl3, N_bl4 = 0,5,1,2
N_bt1, N_bt2, N_bt3, N_bt4 = 2,0,1,2
hL ,bL ,hT ,bT = 150,100,60,40

#Vectors with initial points
Nmat   = [n1,n2,n3,n4]                  # number of MAT layers
Nwr    = [n5,n6]                        # number of WR layers
BL_Mat = [N_bl1, N_bl2, N_bl3, N_bl4]   # longitudinal stiffeners laminated
BT_Mat = [N_bt1, N_bt2, N_bt3, N_bt4]   # transversal stiffeners laminated
DIM    = [hL ,bL ,hT ,bT]               # stiffeners dimensions 
na= [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6]                 # number of layer in bottom panel
NR = [NT,NL]                            # number of bottom stiffeners

#====================== GEKKO FIRST FASE ITERACTIONS ===========================
print(74*"=")
print(74*"=")
print(28*"=","START OPTIMIZATION",28*"=")
start_time = time.time()
print(74*"=")
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False) # Initialize gekko
m.options.IMODE = 3     # solution mode 2 or 3
m.options.SOLVER= 1     # (1=APOPT, 3=IPOPT) APOPT is an MINLP solver
# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 6000', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 6000', \
                    # treat minlp as nlp
                    'minlp_as_nlp 0', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 5000', \
                    # 1 = depth first, 2 = breadth first , 3 , 4
                    'minlp_branch_method 1', \
                    #maximum value to be considered as an integer
                    'minlp_integer_max 2.0e9'\
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1e-5', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.001'\
                    #objective_convergence_tolerance 1.0e-6
                    'constraint_convergence_tolerance 1.0e-6'\
                    #convergence tolerance for the constraints
                    'objective_convergence_tolerance 1.0e-6'] 

#======================= PRINT INITIAL POINTS. =================================
print(8*"..","Initial point for bottom optimization",9*"..")
print("Number of Stiffeners                   [NT,NL] : ",NR)
print("")
print("Bottom Layers              [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5,n6] : ",na)
print("")
print("Long. Stiffeners layers  [bln1,bln2,bln3,bln4] : ",BL_Mat)
print("")
print("Trans. Stiffeners layer  [btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4] : ",BT_Mat)
print("")
print("Stiffeners dimension         [hL,bL,hT,bT][mm] : ",DIM)
print(37*"..")
#============================ DESIGN VARIABLES.=================================
low=1
n1 = m.Var(value=na[0],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='n1')
n2 = m.Var(value=na[1],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='n2')   
n3 = m.Var(value=na[2],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='n3')
n4 = m.Var(value=na[3],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='n4')
n5 = m.Var(value=na[4],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='n5')
n6 = m.Var(value=na[5],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='n6')

NT  = m.Var(value=NR[0],lb=low,ub=10,integer=True,name='NT')
NL  = m.Var(value=NR[0],lb=low,ub=3 ,integer=True,name='NL')

N_bl1 = m.Var(value=BL_Mat[0],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='N_bl1')
N_bl2 = m.Var(value=BL_Mat[1],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='N_bl2')   
N_bl3 = m.Var(value=BL_Mat[2],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='N_bl3')
N_bl4 = m.Var(value=BL_Mat[3],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='N_bl4')
N_bt1 = m.Var(value=BT_Mat[0],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='N_bt1')
N_bt2 = m.Var(value=BT_Mat[1],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='N_bt2')
N_bt3 = m.Var(value=BT_Mat[2],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='N_bt3')
N_bt4 = m.Var(value=BT_Mat[3],lb=low,ub=100,integer=True,name='N_bt4')

hL  = m.Var(value=DIM[0],lb=40,ub=800,integer=False,name='hl')
bL  = m.Var(value=DIM[1],lb=40,ub=800,integer=False,name='bl')
hT  = m.Var(value=DIM[2],lb=40,ub=800,integer=False,name='ht')
bT  = m.Var(value=DIM[3],lb=40,ub=800,integer=False,name='bt')

#============================GEKKO COMPUTATION.=================================
#Stimation of space and span stiffeners
sT, sL, luT, luL = span_space_stiff(NT,NL,Lp,B)

#Stimation of stiffeners forces
pb_T,pb_L,fd_T,fd_L,md_T,md_L = stiff_force(Lwl,BC,V,beta,mLDC,luT,sT,luL,sL)

#Stimation of plate bending moment and shear force
pb_p,fd_p,md_p,l_1,b_1 = plate_force(Lwl,BC,V,beta,mLDC,luT,sT,luL,sL,bL,bT)

#Plate optimiation.
(BOTTOM_WEIGHTS,PANEL_WEIGHT,STIFF_WEIGHT,
 C1L,C2L,C3L,EIL,C45,C46,C1T,C2T,C3T,EIT, C47,C48,C1P,C2P,C3P,
 B_T,EP,tw_l,tw_c,lw_l,lw_c)=bottom_optimize(Lp,B,NT,NL,hL,bL,hT,bT,l_1,b_1,sT,
                                             luT,sL,luL,pb_T,pb_L,fd_T,fd_L,
                                             md_T,md_L,md_p)

#=============================CONSTRAINTS.======================================
# Panel constraints.
# Same number of Mat layers and Wr layers into sub laminate
CON1 = m.Equation(C1P == 0)
# Minimun weight for impact loads
CON2 = m.Equation(C2P -1 >= 0)

#Define Objective function for panel weight minimization
Objective = m.Obj(BOTTOM_WEIGHTS)

m.open_folder()
output = m.solve(disp=True) # Solver
```

Comment: Thanks for your question, Miguel. I edited your question to be more specific. Here are a few suggestions to help you: (1) look at the infeasibilties.txt file in the run folder. You can include `m.Var(name='myVar')` to make this file easier to read (2) avoid equations with divide by zero by reformulating from `x/y==1` to `x==y` (you may need to use `m.Equation` instead of `m.Intermediate` (3) first find a feasible initial guess value by switching from `m.Var` to `m.Param` for your design variables. This question was closed by the moderators. Please post again if you still need help.

Comment: Here is a related problem where a reformulation of `y==1/x` to `y*x==1` helped solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491175/python-optimization-using-gekko Sometimes a `Variable` + `Equation` is easier to solve than an `Intermediate` because it avoids divide by zero. Also, check if the `if3()` or `max3()` functions can be replaced by variable constraints. Here is a related problem that is less complex than yours but has some of the same design characteristics. https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/TubularColumn

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a higher diagnostic level such as `DIAGLEVEL=4`:

```
m.open_folder()
m.options.DIAGLEVEL=4
output = m.solve(disp=True) # Solver
```

In the run folder, you'll see a couple new files that are helpful in diagnosing the problems with the equations. The first is `model_init_values.txt` that shows the initial guesses for the values with the intermediates calculated based on the guess values that you provided. You'll see a number of `NaN` or `Inf` values that likely mean divide by zero.

```
     172                 +Inf kar1
     173           0.00000000 kar2
     174           0.00000000 kar
     175           0.00000000 pbp
     176                  NaN kshc1
     177           0.00000000 kshc
     178                  NaN a1
     179                  NaN a2
     180           0.00000000 k2
     181           0.00000000 fdp
     182           0.00000000 mdp
.
.
.
     195        1311.11111111 wp
     196   917050883.35535383 eal
     197 57906932528.31179047 eazl
     198          63.14473229 nal
     199         151.38044132 zcri
     200 ******************** eaz2l
     201 ******************** ebh3l
     202 ******************** einal
     203 20726655556.62884521 qcl
     204 20720536220.47989273 qwl
     205           0.00000000 eiminl
     206        3025.53188955 sml
     207                 +Inf c1l
     208          22.46255737 awl
     209                 +Inf c2l
     210         141.42371638 acl
     211                 +Inf c3l
     212                 +Inf eil
     213          18.89350536 c45
```

Another helpful file is `model_init_res.txt` that shows the equation residuals (`f(x)==g(x)` residual is `f(x)-g(x)`). These are some of the equation residuals:

```
       6      116          -1.32000000 v24-(((((1-int_v23))*(ad_l1))+((int_v23)*(ad_l2))))
       7      117                 +Inf 0-((((1-int_v25))*((0.25-kar_t1))))-slk_7
       8      118                 -Inf ((int_v25)*((0.25-kar_t1)))-(0)-slk_8
      13      123                 +Inf 0-((((1-int_v29))*((1-kar_t1))))-slk_13
      14      124                 -Inf ((int_v29)*((1-kar_t1)))-(0)-slk_14
      15      125          -0.99000000 v30-(((((1-int_v29))*(1))+((int_v29)*(kar_t2))))
      16      126                 +Inf 0-((((1-int_v31))*((1-kar_l1))))-slk_16
      17      127                 -Inf ((int_v31)*((1-kar_l1)))-(0)-slk_17
      18      128          -0.99000000 v32-(((((1-int_v31))*(1))+((int_v31)*(kar_l2))))
      19      129       -1310.00000000 0-((((1-int_v33))*(((st-bt)-(sl-bl)))))-slk_19
      26      136           0.00000000 0-(((int_v37)*((ad2-ad1))))-slk_26
      27      137           0.00000000 v38-(((((1-int_v37))*(ad1))+((int_v37)*(ad2))))
      28      138                 +Inf 0-((((1-int_v39))*((0.25-kar1))))-slk_28
      29      139                 -Inf ((int_v39)*((0.25-kar1)))-(0)-slk_29
      30      140                 -Inf v40-(((((1-int_v39))*(kar1))+((int_v39)*(0.25))))
      33      143          -0.99000000 v42-(((((1-int_v41))*(1))+((int_v41)*(kar2))))
      34      144                  NaN 0-((((1-int_v43))*((2-((v34)/(v36))))))-slk_34
      35      145                  NaN ((int_v43)*((2-((v34)/(v36)))))-(0)-slk_35
      40      150          13.00000000 c1p-(0)
      41      151          -0.99414611 (c2p-1)-(0)-slk_41
      42      152        6464.36333333 (pw+sw)
```

I recommend that you examine each of the equations and provide an initial guess that produces a finite values. Also, it is a good idea to protect against divide by zero. For example, you can switch an Intermediate equation like `y = m.Intermediate(1/x)` to a variable for `y` and reformulate the equation as `m.Equation(y*x==1)`. I'll be glad to provide additional help on this problem - it looks like a very nice application.